# How to make ssl working in bluehost?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, bluehost

Hi I have this sub domain hosted on bluehost.. 
I have search all over the internet but I guess.. no one has got the problem as I did :(

What I did was added this line of code in .htaccess

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

that is redirecting all urls to https.

But when I visit the site I get

```
https://ci.domain.com/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/user/default/dashboard/start/19
```

FYI: phpinfo() gives me openssl enabled. My .htaccess code:

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

#RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code for forcing HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

**Your complete .htaccess:**

```
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Hi anubhava.. thank you so much for the reply.. but i still got the same prob.. please check above question if you would like to see complete .htaccess code im updating now..

Comment: Can you try adding RewriteCind for file/dir check for your second row also?

Comment: Hi anubhav thnx.. but im not going thru it.. u can check ur self.. at https://ci.flockminer.com

Comment: Have you used above suggested .htaccess and please explain what was your expected behavior and what didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi, yes did replaced my htaccess code with the code you provided but still im getting `https://ci.domain.com/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevronwo/ci/~hevron....` except the first login page. The login pages url changes in https://flockminer.com/~hevronwo/ci

Comment: `https://ci.flockminer.com/` doesn't get redirected when it is served from your web server (I have verified that in curl command line also). There is Javascript on the page that is redirecting the URL after loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

This will force http to https 
`RewriteEngine On` 
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` 
`RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`